# Get only one field from the related table

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have following connection between tables Image:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
@Data
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;
    private byte[] image;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "avatar")
    private Personal personal;
}
```

and Personal

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personal")
@Data
public class Personal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    private String position;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "avatar_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Image avatar;
}
```

I want to get back from my service Personal entities with **ONLY** id field from Image table. Repositories and services are standard from tutorials - without extra code or overrides

Comment: Write a SQL query for your fetch method read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138997/hibernate-left-join-fetch-get-only-an-id-list-of-the-first-table

Answer (score 1):

If read-only is ok use a DTO or interface [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).